# Help to rightly create robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

I have dynamic urls like this.

mydomain.com/?pg=login
mydomain.com/?pg=reguser
mydomain.com/?pg=aboutus
mydomain.com/?pg=termsofuse

When the page is requested for ex. mydomainname.com/?pg=login index.php include login.php file.

some of the urls are converted to static url like
mydomain.com/aboutus.html
mydomain.com/termsofuse.html

I need to allow index mydomainname.com/aboutus.html, mydomainname.com/termsofuse.html
and disallow mydomainname.com/?pg=login, mydomainname.com/?pg=reguser, please help to manage my robots.txt file.

I have also mydomainname.com/posted.php?details=50 (details can have any number) which I converted to mydomainname.com/details/50.html
I need also to allow all this type of urls.

Comment: Is it correct to say that you want to allow all *.html URIs and disallow all *.php URIs for robots?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to only index your static pages, you can use this:

```
Disallow: /*?
```

This will disallow all URLs which contain a question mark.

If you wish to keep indexing posted.php?details=50 URLs, and you have a finite set of params you wish to disallow, you can create a disallow entry for each, like this:

```
Disallow: /?pg=login
```

Or just prevent everything starting with /?

```
Disallow: /?*
```

You can use a tool like this to test a sampling of URLs to see if it will match them or not.

http://tools.seobook.com/robots-txt/analyzer/